# concatenating columns in a dataframe pyspark with null values

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, concatenation

```
Data:
Name1            Name2            Name3(Expected)
RR Industries    null            RR Industries
RR Industries    RR Industries   RR IndustriesRR Industries
```

Code:

```
.withColumn("Name3",F.concat(F.trim(Name1), F.trim(Name2)))
```

Actual result:
The columns with null values are deleted.
I want the output to be as seen in Name3(Expected Columnt)

I think, the issue occurs after the joining the tables
The name column is available in df2 and df3.
before joining they do not contain null values.

Issue:
After joining; since pyspark doesnt delete the common columns, we have two name1 columns from 2 tables
I tried replcaing it with empty string;it didnt work and throws error

How do I replace null values with empty string after joining tables

```
df = df1\
.join(df2,"code",how = 'left') \
.join(df3,"id",how = 'left')\
.join(df4,"id",how = 'left')\
.withColumn('name1',F.when(df2('name1').isNull(),'').otherwise(df2('name1')))\
.withColumn('name1',F.when(df3('name1').isNull(),'').otherwise(df3('name1')))\
.withColumn("Name1",F.concat(F.trim(df2.name1), F.trim(df3.name1)))
```

Comment: If any of the columns in your concat statement are null, the result of the concat is null, that's how it works.  Use `coalesce` to replace the null values with an empty string, and use that for your concat.

Comment: df.fillna is not working...any other examples which I can try

Comment: df=df.withColumn('name2',F.when(F.col('name2').isNull(),' ')
    .otherwise(F.col('name2'))) doesnt work either

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

> It should be implemented in python with minimal change

```scala
   val data =
      """
        |Name1         |   Name2
        |RR Industries |
        |RR Industries |   RR Industries
      """.stripMargin

    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-------------+-------------+
      * |Name1        |Name2        |
      * +-------------+-------------+
      * |RR Industries|null         |
      * |RR Industries|RR Industries|
      * +-------------+-------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Name1: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Name2: string (nullable = true)
      */
    df.withColumn("Name3(Expected)", concat_ws("", df.columns.map(col).map(c => coalesce(c, lit(""))): _*))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
      * |Name1        |Name2        |Name3(Expected)           |
      * +-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
      * |RR Industries|null         |RR Industries             |
      * |RR Industries|RR Industries|RR IndustriesRR Industries|
      * +-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
      */
    df.withColumn("Name3(Expected)", concat_ws("", df.columns.map(col): _*))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
      * |Name1        |Name2        |Name3(Expected)           |
      * +-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
      * |RR Industries|null         |RR Industries             |
      * |RR Industries|RR Industries|RR IndustriesRR Industries|
      * +-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
      */
```

Comment: DO I need to download any libraries for map? I am using pyspark and .map(col): gives error

Comment: no need download any libraries. I'm converting all the column names to column. here `col` means `functions.col`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach in pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName('practice')\
.getOrCreate()

sc= spark.sparkContext

df = sc.parallelize([
("RR Industries",None), ("RR Industries", "RR Industries")]).toDF(["Name1", 
  "Name2"])


 df.withColumn("Name3", F.concat_ws("", F.col("Name1"), 
 F.col("Name2"))).show(truncate=False)

+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
|Name1        |Name2        |Name3                     |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
|RR Industries|null         |RR Industries             |
|RR Industries|RR Industries|RR IndustriesRR Industries|
+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+
```